# Passing data to a webservice using axios from a react application

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have an intellij project running a webservice in localhost:8022. when I run this project
and use this url(http://localhost:8022/api/vi/solutionj/solutionj-requests) to post the data using postman 
it works very well. My data gets written to the database. This simply shows that I can reach this url.

```
{
  "branchId": 1,
  "customerEmail": "john@yahoo.com",
  "firstName": "Johnny",
  "lastName": "Jacob"
}
```

However, I need to pass this data from a react application and on the click of a button
I call the function below. I am using Axios.

I set a breakpoint in my intellij project and I am not able to hit the endpoint. I decided to
think whether am using axios the wrong way.

```
handleDatabaseStorage = (branchId, customerEmail, firstName, lastName) => {
  //webapi url
  const SOLUTIONJ_BASE_URL = `http://localhost:8022/api/vi/solutionj/solutionj-requests`;

  try {
    AXIOS_AUTHED.post(SOLUTIONJ_BASE_URL, {
      branchId: branchId,
      customerEmail: customerEmail,
      firstName: firstName,
      lastName: lastName
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

What am I doing wrong in the code above? I am not getting any error back and the data is 
not written to my database. I need to be able to know if there is an exception. My webservice is expecting
all the fields above.

Comment: This seems like a CORS issue to me. Did you enable CORS on your api ?

Comment: I will need to check that and how to do that? This works from postman anyway

Comment: Postman doesn't care about that its a dev tool. Your having issue on the browser. check this https://enable-cors.org/server.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use .then and .catch to get the success and error response respectively.

```
AXIOS_AUTHED.post(SOLUTIONJ_BASE_URL, {
  branchId: branchId,
  customerEmail: customerEmail,
  firstName: firstName,
  lastName: lastName
},{
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
}).then(res => {
  console.log(res);
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Also should all the items on the left like "branchId" be in quotes? Is that the right format?

Comment: @user2320476 yes keys should be in single or double quote but quotes are required. Check my updated answer

Comment: I initially saw that you put data in the syntax and now it is gone. Did you change this again?

Comment: It depends on how you access the data in the backend. With my current updated code you access properties using req.body.branchId. If you want to send in the data object then req.body.data.branchId. Have you tried with current updated code?

Comment: All the data is written to one field in the database

Comment: Construct your data object in the backend and save it to database

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding you. There is no data object to construct in the backend. I am taking this json data and writing it to a field in the database. This works from postman.

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
const SOLUTIONJ_BASE_URL = `http://localhost:8022/api/vi/solutionj/solutionj-requests`;

let data = {
  branchId: branchId,
  customerEmail: customerEmail,
  firstName: firstName,
  lastName: lastName
}

let reqObj = {
  method:'POST',
  data:data, //above data variable
  url:SOLUTIONJ_BASE_URL    
}

axios(reqObj)
.then((res)=>{console.log(res)})
.catch((err)=>{console.log(err)})
```